# How to prevent LOG print using Proguard in android in Release build

Tags: java, android, android-logcat

I am using Android studio 2.2.2 gradle.
I am using Proguard in build.gradle in this way.

```
 buildTypes {

    release {

        // Enable ProGuard
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        // Common release options
        zipAlignEnabled true
        debuggable false
        jniDebuggable false

        // Notice that the default ProGuard file (SDK-provided) also enables optimization
        // Here we also include a third file which disables the logging (see below)
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'


    }

    debug {
        // We enable ProGuard also for debug builds
        minifyEnabled true

        // Notice that the default ProGuard file (SDK-provided) differs from the release one
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

And here is my proguard...

```
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod

-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontwarn     org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementatio Registry

-keep class * extends android.

 -assumenosideeffects class    android.util.Log { *; }

 -assumenosideeffects class                  java.io.PrintStream {
public void println(...);
public void print(...);
}
```

Now when in my MainActivity.java i check something in oncreate--

```
 int i=0;
 Log.d(TAG,"i val:"+i++);
 Toast i value
```

And output always "i val:1". Now my question is why the log line is executed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log line or system.out is just a method to print in console (phone log file)
even if this is the release build it will get executed
if you want to block the logs in release build follow this steps:

Create a class like this:

```
public class LogTag {
  public  static void d(String msg){
    if (ApplicationClass.isDebug){
        Log.d("log_tag", msg);
    }
  }

  public  static void v(String msg){
    if (ApplicationClass.isDebug){
        Log.v("log_tag", msg);
    }
  }
  public  static void e(String msg,Exception e){
    if (ApplicationClass.isDebug){
        Log.e("log_tag", msg, e);
    }
  }
  public  static void e(String msg){
    if (ApplicationClass.isDebug){
        Log.e("log_tag", msg);
    }
  }
}
```

Now in application class init isDebug variable

```
public static boolean isDebug = BuildConfig.DEBUG;
```

then print your logs like this

```
LogTag.d('message...');
```

else add this lines in proguard

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
     public static * d(...);
     public static * w(...);
     public static * v(...);
     public static * i(...);
}
```

let's look in deeper if you decompile the apk this is the code you will have which is :

```
    Log.d("TAG", "TAG");
    int i = 0 + 1;
    Log.d("TAG", "i val:" + 0);
    System.out.println("i:" + i);
```

original

```
    Log.d("TAG","TAG");
    int i=0;
    Log.d("TAG","i val:"+i++);
    System.out.println("i:"+i);
```

so as you can see compilers will change as we are trying to optimize and remove Log.d

let's took another example
decompiled code:

```
    int index = 0;
    while (index < 10) {
        int i2 = i + 1;
        Log.d("TAG", "i val:" + i);
        index++;
        i = i2;
    }
    System.out.println("i:" + i);
```

original code:

```
    for(int index = 0;index<10;index++){
        Log.d("TAG","i val:"+i++);
    }
    System.out.println("i:"+i);
```

Comment: I don't want to use this that's why i do this using Proguard.

Comment: replace 
-assumenosideeffects class    android.util.Log { *; }
to
this
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** w(...);
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** i(...);
}

Comment: If you're going to do something like that, I suggest you take a much better approach and instead rely on Timber by Jake Warthon. https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber It's literally ONE class and will already allow you to log to Crashlytics or similar in release, and what not.

Comment: @parth main wo bhi use kara tha lekin kam nahi bana.

Comment: @MartínMarconcini i don't want to use timber

Comment: @Subho that's perfectly valid, try leaving only this in your release:     `minifyEnabled true` and `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'` I was under the impression those two were enough these days.